# Can't output Elastic Beanstalk log to CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to set up logging for a program using on Elastic Beanstalk and .NET Core. I want to output log entries to CloudWatch. I'm following the instructions https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet.

I'm wondering what I'm missing. This page looks relevant: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html It has a screenshot for configuring CloudWatch Logs. Does anyone know how to access that page for configuring CloudWatch logs?? I couldn't find it any of the config settings for the Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get logging working by adding the correct IAM permission listed in the documentation here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html

```
{   "Version": "2012-10-17",   "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:GetLogEvents",
        "logs:PutLogEvents",
        "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
        "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
        "logs:PutRetentionPolicy"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:*:*"
      ]
    }   ] }
```